# Draw the path based on touch events

Tags: android

my activity contains some Buttons and an EditText. I set the onTouchListeners for all the buttons and its aim is to draw the path based on the touch events that happens on buttons(swype keyboard). Problem is that I unable to draw the path.how to make it possible?
post the sample code if possible.